# How to navigate a carousel in Bootstrap using button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="click"/>
    <div class="container">
      <!--for carousel -->
      <div class="well">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" id="first_carousel">                       
              <a href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next" id="next_carousel" class="pull-right">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- First Carousel -->
            <div class="item" id="second_carousel">
              <!-- Second Carousel -->
              <a class="col-xs-1" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              </a>
              <strong>My Details</strong>          
            </div>
            <!-- Second Carousel -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Well -->
    </div>
    <!-- Container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on the button, I want to navigate to the 2nd slide of the carousel. I tried action="#second_slide" but it didn't work. Is there any other workaround using jQuery or Bootstrap?

Here's what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/difawayufa/edit?html,output

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h please refer this .Did this help you.

Comment: @smraj - That's too basic. Anyway found out what I was looking for from the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with jquery with the following :

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click" onclick=" $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('next');"/>
```

You can also use :
     $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('prev');

If you want to go to the previous slide

EDIT :
If you want to go to specific slide, you can use the index of the slide :

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click" onclick=" $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(1);"/>
```

Comment: But if I click the button again, it comes back to Slide-1. I want the button only to move to next - if I click it the second time it should stay in that slide itself. Is it possible to achieve that in jQuery?

Comment: You can use the id :<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click" onclick=" $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(1);"/> It will go only to the second slide

Comment: Works like a charm. You saved my life. Thank you so much :)